# Local notification with phone call

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

How can I keep detecting if a phone call is active whether the app is on background or in front so that I can send a local notification to the user when someone calls?

I use this code to detect if a phone call is active

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>
CTCallCenter * callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
    if([callCenter currentCalls] ) {
        NSLog(@"phone call");
    }
```

I use a device to test the app.

Comment: Why do you want to send a local notification when the phone will let the user know already when there is a call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the app is running in the foreground, you can detect an incoming call with the [Core Telephony Framework.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html)

To detect calls while in background, you can use [CTCallCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604) if your app falls into any of these [categories provided by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html):

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background,
  such as a music player app
- Apps that record audio content while in the background
- Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such
  as a navigation app
- Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
- Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
- Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories