# iOS local Notification is not receiving at the time of phone call is on

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I am developing one iOS app where I am creating local notification. Its working fine for me. But when there is an phone call is on at that time local notification is not generating. i.e banner is not showing at the time which i have set for local notification.
please any idea about the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: means are you use NSNotificationCenter right?

Comment: I am creating UILocalNotification object to generate local notification

Comment: Sorry, no idea for UILocalNotification but,Here is the link which I share I hope this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19588701/3378413